# Writing to XML file by java not working

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to create node named Log which contains these tags date,message,type. I have written a function that does my job. Somehow it doesn't generate any exceptions, but still it is not working. I am not getting that tag. Can anyine tell me where I have gone wrong?

```
void writeToXML(String date,String message,String type)
{
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse("D:\\Log.xml");
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        Element newlog = document.createElement("log");
        Element name = document.createElement("date");
        name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date));
        Element name1 = document.createElement("type");
        name1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(type));
        Element name2 = document.createElement("message");
        name2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        newlog.appendChild(name);
        newlog.appendChild(name1);
        newlog.appendChild(name2);
        root.appendChild(newlog);
        System.out.println(root.getTextContent()+"     "+document.getTextContent());

        System.out.println("Dude working");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `TransformerFactory` to save the changes.

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("D:\\Log.xml"));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @hackerdarshi